# How to revert Chrome's tab ribbons to before late 2024 March version?

Tags: google-chrome

Today I found my Chrome adopting the following style for tab ribbons

[image]

Before today, the tab ribbons were solidly colored and there were no vertical bars in between.

The problem of this new UI for me is that the added transparent spaces make it difficult to select a tab (among many) accurately and speedily.

Is there a way to disable the new change?

I tried looking for tab related flags but couldn't find anything that appear relevant to experiment with

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'll find it in:

> chrome://flags/

With the following name:

> Customize Chrome Side Panel

Disable that and relaunch chrome and they will be gone. At least until a future update where they move it under a new flag (again). This also turns off the tab search bar, for what it's worth.